# Effective method for sharing common functions of an interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

Okay, quick disclaimer, I come from the world of C++ and have been only using Typescript for the past month or so. It's probably fair to say at this point that I'm a bit clumsy with Typescript.

With that out of the way, I'm using Typescript with pixi.js.

I've abstracted the pixi.js display objects with a `DisplayObject` interface. One of the main purposes of this interface is to provide an interface for real world space versus the pixi.js coordinate system. There are some other reasons I'm doing this, since it will make handling `DisplayObject`'s easier if I have a common interface I can work through.

An example of what `DisplayObject` looks like is the following:

```
export interface DisplayObject {
    // These are in "game space" (Cartesian)
    getX(): number;
    setX(val: number): void;
    getY(): number;
    setY(val: number): void;

    // These are in "screen space" (canvas coordinates: upper left, +Y down)
    getScreenX(): number;
    setScreenX(val: number): void;
    getScreenY(): number;
    setScreenY(val: number): void;
}
```

What I do is then create specific display objects, such as a sprite that `implements` from `DisplayObject` and `extends` from the appropriate pixi.js class.

For example, `Sprite` would look like the following:

```
export class Sprite extends PIXI.Sprite implements DisplayObject {
}
```

What I have found is that the code for setting the x/y values and/or screen x/y values will generally be the same. But I cannot generically associate code with the interface.

Is there a good way to share this common code? Or is there a better way to use `interface` and `classes` to improve the design.

All display object classes derive from a pixi.js class. And those pixi.js classes themselves `extend` from a `PIXI.Container` class.

I know how to do this in C++ as well as Swift, but Typescript doesn't have the support multiple inheritance. Or perhaps Typescript has something similar to Swift's `extension`s?

Comment: Perhaps baking that functionality into an [abstract class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes) and extending it?

Comment: How would I then extend from the appropriate pixi.js class? Sorry if that sounds dumb, from my reading, it seems I can't extend from 2 different classes?

Comment: Ah, sure, I see.  No, I think you're correct on that front.  Could you have the abstract class extend PIXI.Sprite and all your other classes extend the abstract class?  (I'm just bouncing ideas here-- I've done some Typescript but I'm not an expert here yet on the best ways to organize more complex class structures).

Comment: Ideas are always good to throw out there. No. because `PIXI.Sprite` is just one example of a class. For example, other display types can `extends` from `PIXI.Graphics` or even `PIXI.Container`. All pixi draw types do derive from `PIXI.Container`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Mixins to solve this problem. I based it off this excellent article:

https://www.bryntum.com/blog/the-mixin-pattern-in-typescript-all-you-need-to-know/